# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' in a generic type assignment

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying a generic derived type `AssingValueType` as follows.

```
export interface ObjectArray {
    externalId: string
}

export interface CarFilters {
  arrayType: string[];
  objectType: ObjectArray[];
}

export type FilterOptionValue = string | number;

export type FilterMapValue = FilterOptionValue[] | string;

export interface ShipFilters {
  [key: number]: FilterMapValue;
}

type AppliedFiltersType = {
    cars: CarFilters;
    ships: ShipFilters;
}

type PathValue<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = T[K] extends unknown ? T[K] : never;

export type AssingValueType<
  Category extends keyof AppliedFiltersType = keyof AppliedFiltersType, 
  Key extends keyof PathValue<AppliedFiltersType, Category> = keyof PathValue<AppliedFiltersType, Category>
> = {
  category: Category,
  filterKey: Key
  value: PathValue<AppliedFiltersType[Category], Key>;
}
```

I expect `filterKey` can only be key of a respective category object.

eg
if category is `car` then `filterKey` can be `arrayType` or `ObjectType` and value can be array or `ObjectArray` based on the `filterKey`

Followring test expression to assign type gives the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`.

```
const test1: AssingValueType = {
  category: 'cars',
  filterKey: 'arrayType',
  value: ['dfd']
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=2&pln=38&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeQCMArYbGAQSikwE84BvAKDjlFSiUwBsBJAEwBccAM4woyAOZMAvkyahIsRCjRZccAMKYoAMQTcOIxizg6atACq0wwYWIlJJAbQC6AblMQSZGNdvCRKTkVBZunnIK4NDwMDZ4%20oZo%20GAwCBBIAGo8AK54ALyi4lJwAD5wSDkAtoRonlFKsfFwiRwAsphg2dx5cIWtyanpWbnAbmVFjpL1ijEqHOp4AMoAFghgA1DGzKzOANbAtMKVNWiuwpsdXaMR8rPKyAs4eBRgYEswmKgmrJ1g3AhgPxNiJhK9-oDgQYjP5gLcmHFbHBwQCgSDYX0fqw4NgdKCtDoQZ5saI1mB8at1kTZPJEXgAApfFbdPIAHksbBAqCQ-GM3mCMAANHAANKc7m8uAHWgQdBwDmFaWy%20UAPkxlmcItc4uAPOMOSQeyQEAA7kg4AB%20eWa7XHYAANzqd2iyjpyJEIikLOAsNZpm0qEk0Ho7F1kqVcpRkPRzUVh2VUbR0LQIlhwtMIsOOr1UvjcsZMGZo1ZiahSS2aYJgeDarjMvzTO9JbeqLLMPiwoDwCDUFoKsFTFrWNx1d7wi7PdoA9Y6GTUEzR1Fh2ncHto2EBaLPWAzYhSfLqfizgnwdcwoXKvh2AyYjgqDEAEYwR6vaMMYUdjivt3g8IAOS4lsf4rrO5YLv%205h0LCwGmGu27CM4f78Og-B-q4shAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are ok, but you are missing a vehicle for inference. Without a function call to allow inference from the assign value the `Category` and `Key` generic type parameters will just have their default values.

The only way to infer those types from the value is to use a function call:

```
function makeAssingValueType<Category extends keyof AppliedFiltersType, Key extends keyof PathValue<AppliedFiltersType, Category>>(v: AssingValueType<Category, Key>) {
    return v;
}
const test1 = makeAssingValueType({
  category: 'cars',
  filterKey: 'arrayType',
  value: ['dfd']
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeQCMArYbGAQSikwE84BvAWACg525RUolMAbAJIATAFxwAzjCjIA5qwC+rVqEixEKNFlxwAwpigAxBH27jGrdvpq0AKrTDAxk6UhkBtALoBuC3AgkyGDsHMSJSciprTx8WRRZlcGh4GHs8IxM0fDAYBAgkADV+AFc8AF4JKVk4AB84JCKAW0I0GITVZNS4dO4AWUwwQr4SuHLuzOzcguLgTxqKlxlWlhUk9W4tPABlAAsEMDGoM2Y2ODcAa2BaMXqmtA8xA76B6Zi41hSHOAowMD4EYCEB3EwTK5hO7Gw+nEYj0hmMphiHAkuzA0LgOz2QNeShYHzwAAVMDBtoMSgAeGycECoJBCMz+cIwAA0cAA0lSaXS4BdaBB0HBKeUeXyBQA+EYCtysjwc4C0sxFJBnJAQADuSDgAH5JdK4NdgAA3Fo4lZqPFfcTiWSk4Agsm+PSoGTQehcOVc4X876-f6A+FoYGdIWXEXev4AoEglm+VmXWXy7kh-mE4k2slh32R1Isx3AZ1QWji4O85NEknTdM-cN+jKHKO6Il5l2i1hFsEQxv5q4Np0upm+dD+qCx7sj3wG6ZiFPlobASs+iNDwMONy5rseFkj0XYljoRXkSZwBqYC4US3W6Z2tcu+MepNfKuZpf1ke3syeuDTtMZxe15fAHNO2bUUAAoDTEM8rVcG0ryAgtN0uUUAEp2w4KBgBgIoeDgA0d2wPJJDgVBJAARglY9T3PaDL1SEDjg7XsCzEABySFDmY-sTkHWsRxYqw6BBDjx0nU5mKEdAhGYjwFCQoA)

Comment: I want to use this type in a redux toolkit `createAction`. Just couldn't figure out how to do it. Tried something like createAction<AssingValueType>('MY_TYPE'); The generated function was giving the same error. I wonder how to infer the type there.